# child container component Reactjs and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Quick simple question regarding React and Redux.  Are you allowed to have a parent  container component(thats interacting with redux store) render another child container component(that is also reacting to the store)?. this child component here, has it's own state to manage and is not a presentational component.

Comment: Yes, you are allowed. Please check footnotes from Redux creator here https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: Yes, possible. It is also possible to create another provider. For eg. check out redux-falcor, which provides a provider for a Falcor model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's completely fine to do this. This is pretty much what will happen:

1. Action dispatched
2. Store triggers 'change'
3. Child `connect`ed component is re-rendered.
4. Parent `connect`ed component is re-rendered which in turn re-renders the Child `connect`ed component however because `connect()` implements `shouldComponentUpdate` for you it'll short circuit this second Child re-render unless the props passed in from the parent have changed.